# If $A_k$ is the k-rank approximation for an incidence matrix with SVD, is $A_k$ related to the best incidence matrix approximation of $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to study the SVD over an incidence matrix. So $A_k$ is the best k-rank approximation wrt the Frobenius norm. Since I wanna filter out "noises" and get a new incidence matrix, I am thinking if I apply a cutoff value $c$ to each element of $A-A_k$ such that if the absolute value is greater than $c$, flip the value in $A$. Thus I call it $A^{01}_k$. So does $A-A^{01}_k$ minimize the  Frobenius norm for all other matrix $B$s with the cutoff applied? The same as, is $A^{01}_k$ the best incidence approximation? (A transformation by a unit step function. I can image that an $f(x)=cx$ still makes it a best approximation.)

Thanks